# How to avoid coupling to a representation in Play 2.3?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

The [RESTful example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonHttp) Action in the Play 2.3 docs reads:

```
def listPlaces = Action {
  val json = Json.toJson(Place.list)
  Ok(json)
}
```

What makes the method tightly coupled to this specific JSON format.

Is it possible to have the service logic separated from content representation, for example as JAX-RS does with [MessageBody Writers and Readers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)?

Answer (score 1):

`Ok(json)` is actually calling [`Status.apply`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Results$Status). It requires a [`play.api.http.Writeable[A]`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.http.Writeable), which is something that can transform `A` to a byte array and return the content type for `A`. In your case `A` stands for `JsValue`.

What you can do is to go a step further and supply a `Writeable[Place]`, so you can write something like this:

```
def listPlaces(implicit writeable: Writeable[Place]) = Action {
  Ok(Place.list)
}
```

I assume you already have a `Writes[Place]`. All that's left is to implement a generic function that converts json `Writes` to http `Writeable`:

```
implicit def jsonWritesToHttpWriteable[A](jsWrites: Writes[A])
                                         (implicit writeable: Writeable[JsValue]): Writeable[A] =
  writeable.map(jsWrites.writes)
```

Now, having defined this conversion function as implicit, you can just supply the `Writes[Place]` when you call `listPlaces`:

```
val listPlacesJson = listPlaces(placeJsonWrites)
```

Of course, your route must point to `listPlacesJson` now.